# How do you make sub-widgets of gtk custom widgets editable in Glade?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm making custom Gtk+ widgets (in C) for work and one of the requirements is that those widgets have to be editable in Glade.

So far it works nicely, I have for example a widget made of a table with buttons in it and with a custom specific behaviour and some custom specific properties that can be edited in Glade correctly.

So this work but I need now to allow the user to change the properties of buttons (that are inside my custom widget) - and only those buttons - from Glade.

It seems to be possible as a lot of basic Gtk widgets (a lot of containers) are exposing some of their sub-widgets in glade, allowing for example to edit the label of a GtkFrame.

But I can't find any documentation on that. Can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I've found the answer (after several day of searching and asking on the Gtk forum).

The main idea is that the code that make sub-widgets visible in glade, and in fact all the specific visual behaviour specific in glade, is written in a C pluggin loaded by glade.

First, you can see in [the catalog file provided by Glade for Gtk+](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glade3/tree/plugins/gtk+/gtk+.xml.in) that there are names of functions with `glade_gtk_` prefixes. Those functions are provided in [the C plugin where you can see that functions](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glade3/tree/plugins/gtk+/glade-gtk.c?id=GLADE_3_6_1&bcsi_scan_0FB23122DF0CD2C6=0&bcsi_scan_filename=glade-gtk.c) uses the glade API to add widget adaptors to Glade.

Those adaptors then allow the targetted widgets to be visible in glade.

In fact I've found some documentation that I didnt finished to read yet : http://library.gnome.org/devel/gladeui/stable/catalog.html

Someone confirmed : http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?p=18030#18030